# AWK: Compare two CSV files

Tags: shell, scripting, awk, cygwin

I have two CSV files and I want to compare them using AWK and generate a new file.

file1.csv:

```
"no","loc" 
"abc121","C:/pro/in" 
"abc122","C:/pro/abc"
"abc123","C:/pro/xyz"
"abc124","C:/pro/in"
```

file2.csv:

```
"no","loc" 
"abc121","C:/pro/in"
"abc122","C:/pro/abc"
"abc125","C:/pro/xyz"
"abc126","C:/pro/in"
```

output.csv:

```
"file1","file2","Diff" 
"abc121","abc121","Match" 
"abc122","abc122","Match" 
"abc123","","Unmatch" 
"abc124","","Unmatch" 
"","abc125","Unmatch" 
"","abc126","Unmatch"
```

Comment: A single example is not a description of a problem.  Simply trying to describe the problem in detail will often lead directly to the obvious solution.

Comment: Rather than using `awk`, I would talk a look at the options to the `diff` command, which allow for such line-by-line formatting. (GNU diff only, though?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way with `awk`:

#### script.awk:

```
BEGIN {
    FS = ","
}

NR>1 && NR==FNR {
    a[$1] = $2
    next
}

FNR>1 { 
    print ($1 in a) ? $1 FS $1 FS "Match" : "\"\"" FS $1 FS "Unmatch"
    delete a[$1] 
}

END {
    for (x in a) {
        print x FS "\"\"" FS "Unmatch"
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file1.csv file2.csv
"abc121","abc121",Match
"abc122","abc122",Match
"","abc125",Unmatch
"","abc126",Unmatch
"abc124","",Unmatch
"abc123","",Unmatch
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use `awk` alone, but if I understood the gist of what you're asking correctly, I think this long one-liner should do it...

```
join -t, -a 1 -a 2 -o 1.1 2.1 1.2 2.2 file1.csv file2.csv | awk -F, '{ if ( $3 == $4 ) var = "\"Match\""; else var = "\"Unmatch\"" ; print $1","$2","var }' | sed -e '1d' -e 's/^,/"",/' -e 's/,$/,"" /' -e 's/,,/,"",/g'
```

Description:

- The `join` portion takes the two CSV files, joins them on the first column (default behavior of `join`) and outputs all four fields (`-o 1.1 2.1 1.2 2.2`), making sure to include rows that are unmatched for both files (`-a 1 -a 2`).
- The `awk` portion takes that output and replaces combination of the 3rd and 4th columns to either `"Match"` or `"Unmatch"` based on if they do in fact match or not. I had to make an assumption on this behavior based on your example.
- The `sed` portion deletes the "no","loc" header from the output (`-e '1d'`) and replaces empty fields with open-close quote marks (`-e 's/^,/"",/' -e 's/,$/,""/' -e 's/,,/,"",/g'`). This last part might not be necessary for you.

EDIT:
As tripleee points out, the above fails if the two initial files are unsorted. Here's an updated command to fix that. It punts the header line and sorts each file before passing them to join...

```
join -t, -a 1 -a 2 -o 1.1 2.1 1.2 2.2 <( sed 1d file1.csv | sort ) <( sed 1d file2.csv | sort ) | awk -F, '{ if ( $3 == $4 ) var = "\"Match\""; else var = "\"Unmatch\"" ; print $1","$2","var }' | sed -e 's/^,/"",/' -e 's/,$/,""/' -e 's/,,/,"",/g'
```

Comment: `join` requires sorted input, though. At a minimum, you'll need to trim those header lines. (They are obnoxious anyway.)