# Efficient way to find the differences in 2 csv files

Tags: java, csv, awk

I have 2 large ( say 300,000 * 100) rectangular csv files which have same number of corresponding rows and columns. I need to find the differences if any between each corresponding cell in the 2 files.
Program should o/p the row and cell number that are different and the contents that are different.

Since the number of rows/columns is very large , I'm looking for the most efficient way to do this.

Initially I started exploring with awk , and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391023/awk-compare-two-csv-files) looked promising , but I haven't worked with awk before and was unsuccessful in extending this to 100 columns instead of 2 as in the example

Next , I tried a sort of brute force approach using Java - Load the files into 2 2-D arrays. Initialize 100 threads, each working on a given column , and when a difference is found, each thread puts in the row,cell and diff values into a HashMap (with column number as Key). I did try optimizing it by comparing while reading the second file into the array , but really since I'm visiting each cell, there is no way it can be fast (Took almost 8 hours to complete the comparison)

I'm ok with either awk or Java. And open to any other entirely different approach.

Comment: What about just using `diff` to check for differences in the files? The output could be stored in a file or used in script to analyze further and take appropriate actions.

Comment: That is exactly what the current program is doing. diff just prints the entire line , and in many cases say 10 lines from left file , followed by 10 lines in the right file. So one has to manually copy into say excel and compare visually each column. Note that 90% of the rows have some difference.. so the diff o/p is pretty large

Comment: And what about letting excel sort it out? Not fully up to speed with it's functions but I believe some matrix search could be applied to multiple tabs and maybe change background colors?

Comment: A couple of info needed: how many differences do you expect on average for line? Also,  what are the data types? Mixed (text/dates/numbers)  or just  numbers?

Comment: anywhere between 1 - 10 for each row. Data is mixed. In 80% of the cases if a difference appears in a row for a column , the same will be present in most rows. So I'm now thinking of doing a selective compare (maybe some logic to traverse only portion of rows , fix the issue causing difference and re-run which will cause it to compare other rows ) Not clear yet, but something on those lines would be helpful

Comment: If in Java, I’d look into libraries for reading CSV files. I believe there are a couple of open source libraries out there. (The answer given for awk looks quite promising  in my eyes, though.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

It's a no-brainer to do this in `awk`

```
$ paste -d, file.1 file.2 | 
  awk -F, '{m=NF/2; for(i=1;i<=m;i++) if($i!=$(i+m)) print NR,i,$i,$(i+m)}'
```

prints "row# column# left right" values of the unequal cells.

If you want to print a key column in addition to the row number, you can add it easily

```
$ paste -d, file.1 file.2 | 
  awk -F, -v key=8 '{m=NF/2; 
                     for(i=1;i<=m;i++) 
                       if($i!=$(i+m)) print $key,NR,i,$i,$(i+m)}'
```

Comment: Is it possible to o/p the value of a fixed column (say value of 8th column) in the output? this particular value is guaranteed to be same in both as its a unique key for the rows

Comment: If you try this with your files please post the timing, it shouldn't be more than a min or so.

Comment: Awesome.. took about 1.5 minutes to complete. Ofcourse the Java version had extra output , but useless because of the slowness. Will accept this answer. I should be able to work with the o/p further to get what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something to consider:

```
$ cat file1
1,2,aa
1,2,3
1,bb,3
1,2,3

$ cat file2
1,2,cc
1,2,3
1,dd,3
1,2,3

$ diff file1 file2 |
awk -F, '
    /^[0-9]/ { row=$0+0; next }
    sub(/^< /,"") { split($0,a); next }
    sub(/^> /,"") { for (col=1;col<=NF;col++) if ($col != a[col]) print row, col, a[col], $col }
'
1 3 aa cc
3 2 bb dd
```

That should be extremely fast since it only executes awk and does the loop on the lines that have differences, not all lines.

Answer (score 1):

[univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial)' CSV parser won't take much longer than 5 seconds to process this:

```
public void diff(File leftInput, File rightInput) {
    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings(); //many config options here, check the tutorial

    CsvParser leftParser = new CsvParser(settings);
    CsvParser rightParser = new CsvParser(settings);

    leftParser.beginParsing(leftInput);
    rightParser.beginParsing(rightInput);

    String[] left;
    String[] right;

    int row = 0;
    while ((left = leftParser.parseNext()) != null && (right = rightParser.parseNext()) != null) {
        row++;
        if (!Arrays.equals(left, right)) {
            System.out.println(row + ":\t" + Arrays.toString(left) + " != " + Arrays.toString(right));
        }
    }

    leftParser.stopParsing();
    rightParser.stopParsing();
}
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).